# mongo db. Group documents to one document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have aggregation pipeline which group documents by date and action fields. :

```
[{
    $match: {
        'dt_field': {
            "$gte": ISODate('2022-11-17'),
            "$lt": ISODate('2022-11-23')
        }
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "scores",
        localField: "action",
        foreignField: "action",
        as: "score"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$score"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                    date: {
                        $toDate: "$dt_field"
                    }
                }
            },
            action: "$action"
        },
        actions_count: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        total_score: {
            $sum: "$score.score"
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        '_id.date': 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            date: "$_id.date",
            action: "$_id.action"
        },
        date_actions: {
            $push: {
                action: "$_id.action",
                actions_count: "$actions_count",
                total_score: "$total_score"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            action: "$_id.action"
        },
        date_actions: {
            $push: {
                date: "$_id.date",
                action: "$_id.action",
                actions_count: {
                    "$arrayElemAt": ["$date_actions.actions_count", 0]
                },
                action_total_sc: {
                    "$arrayElemAt": ["$date_actions.total_score", 0]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

It pipeline give me grouped documents by action and day of this action:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "action_1"
        },
        "date_actions": [
            {
                "date": "2022-11-18",
                "action": "action_1",
                "actions_count": 4,
                "action_total_sc": 12
            },
            {
                "date": "2022-11-17",
                "action": "action_1",
                "actions_count": 7,
                "action_total_sc": 21
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "action": "action_2"
        },
        "date_actions": [
            {
                "date": "2022-11-18",
                "action": "action_2",
                "actions_count": 10,
                "action_total_sc": 10
            },
            {
                "date": "2022-11-17",
                "action": "action_2",
                "actions_count": 10,
                "action_total_sc": 10
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

How i can modify my pipeline to get next result. I need get single document which should contain res_date like array of arrays with data inside which i provide in comments in code and field act_stat with array of objects which contain action_name and sum of actions_count and total_score for every actions :

```
{
    "res_date": [
        ["2022-11-17", 17, 31],
        # 1 array elem it is data from field date_actions.date
        # 2 array elem it is summ of all actions_count by this date
        # 3 array elem it is summ of all action_total_sc by this date
        ["2022-11-18", 14, 22]
    ],
    "act_stat": [
        {
            "action_name": "action_1",
            "actions_count": 11,
            "total_score": 33
        },
        {
            "action_name": "action_2",
            "actions_count": 20,
            "total_score": 20
        }
    ],
    "tot": {
        "ac": 31,
        "po": 53
    }
}
```